# Hiding enum methods Java

Tags: java, methods, enums, overriding

Is it possible to hide enum method depends on enum variable?

```
   enum Row1  {
    MainRow1() {
        Row2 getUpg1() {
            return Row2.UPGR1;
        }
        Row2 getUpg2() {
            return Row2 .UPGR2;
        }
        Row2 getUpg3() {
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }


    }, MainRow2() {
        Row2 getUpg3() {
            return Row2 .UPGR3;
        }
    };


    Row2 getUpg1() { return null;}

    Row2 getUpg2() { return null; }

    Row2 getUpg3() {return null; }
}   enum Row2{...}
```

After this I want to invoke `Row1`, but how can I disable option `Row1.MainRow1.getUpg3`?

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can't do that in Java. All instances of an enum are objects of the same class; so there is no way from having some objects implement an interface, and others not to.

Theoretically, you could be writing code like

```
public enum Whatever {
  A, B;

  void foo() {
    if (this == A) {
      throw new RuntimeException("foo() should not be called on A");
    }
```

but that would be a really bad idea.

You might want to read about the [Liskov substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) principle to get an idea why that is (that principle is about interfaces for classes and subclasses; but in essence, your idea is not so much different).